# Why is my if statement in Python evaluating to False?

Tags: python, file, loops, if-statement

My task is to have the user input a year and use that input to search line-by-line within a text file for the total number of gold medals won that year by Olympian athletes. The text file contains thousands of entries sorted like this:

```
LAST_NAME
FIRST_NAME
YEAR
POSITION
\n
```

I thought the way to do it would be to make sure the year matches, and if it does, set the value of a variable called `blockIsValid` to `True`. The program would then check if the block is valid (so as to avoid considering the gold medals of other years) and if it is, check for a gold medal by looking for a one (the position, indicating gold). `blockIsValid` is then reset to `False` after the gold medal is recorded in the variable `goldMedals`.

The checking the year part works but it never finds gold and instead shows this every time:[image] [NOTE] We're supposed to check every single line which is why there are a bunch of lines that say "incorrect year!"

```
def findAnnualMedals(year):
    blockIsValid = None
    goldMedals = 0
    file = open('athletes.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    for currentLine, line in enumerate(file):
        if line.strip() == year:
            print("Correct year!")
            blockIsValid = True
        else:
            print("Incorrect year!")
            blockIsValid = False


        if blockIsValid == True:
            if line.strip() == "1":
                print("Gold!")
                goldMedals += 1

            else:
                print("Not gold!")
            blockIsValid = False
```

Comment: Because `line.strip()` never equals `"1"`.

Comment: You need to go to the next line after checking for the year. Right now, both ``line.strip()`` calls are acting on the _same_ line.

Comment: You're printing `Incorrect year!` for all the lines that contain names and positions.

Comment: @parsimoni, But doesn't the for loop go through all the lines and run the if statements on each one?

Comment: Yes, but within a single loop, ``line`` is the same variable. ``line`` only gets incremented to the next line after the whole body of the loop has finished executing.

Comment: Go on to the next line first.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, If I knew how to do that I would.

Comment: are you doing the same course as @joestuff - you are dealing with very similar problems, with similar input data :-).

Comment: Likely; this is work for a university intro CS class. I considered changing around the variable names before I posted here and I guess that would probably have been a good idea :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll be easier if you rearrange the logic a bit. Put the gold medal check at the top in front of the year check.

```
foundYear = False

for currentLine, line in enumerate(file):
    if foundYear:
        if line.strip() == "1":
            print("Gold!")
            goldMedals += 1

        else:
            print("Not gold!")

        foundYear = False

    elif line.strip() == year:
        print("Correct year!")
        foundYear = True

    else:
        print("Incorrect year!")
```

Comment: Nothing to make you feel stupid like a simple code rearrangement. Thanks, works perfectly. :P

Comment: I don't know if you saw but the first answer I submitted was wrong. I said to just put a `continue` in the first if statement. Had to delete my answer and rethink it a bit. I felt a bit stupid, too. ;-)